# Перевод двоичного отрицательного в десятичное число

Tags: java, c++, математика, системы-счисления, теория

Всем известен метод перевода **dec-to-bin** и **bin-to-dec**, а также онлайн ресурсы (калькулятор) для этого, например [здесь](http://calculatori.ru/perevod-chisel.html)

Также известен способ перевода отрицательного десятично в двоичную систему.
Все это хорошо описано в массе ресурсов, например [здесь](https://repetitors.info/library.php?sposoby_perevoda_chisel).
Исходя из примера, в выше упомянутом источнике, -79 = 10110001

**ВОПРОС:**
Как перевести двоичное (отрицательное) в десятичное число (правильное, тоже отрицательное)?

Сам лично, что то не помню и теряюсь в догадках, а теорию - почему-то я не нашел.

**Догадка:** держать флаг для +-

Comment: У Вас что, на входе строка а надо получить целое?

Comment: По Вашей ссылке описан перевод -79 => 10110001. Вам надо сделать всё то же в обратном порядке. И да - сначала определите и запомните знак будущего десятичного числа.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не столь важно, важна теория перевода, как это описал Akina

Comment: @ Akina - Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от способа представления двоичного знакового числа. Есть код с дополнением до 2, с дополнением до 1, есть и другие варианты. И алгоритм перевода зависит от того, какое представление вы используете.

Например, есть представление, когда есть знаковый бит, а все остальное - беззнаковое значение (при этом есть два нуля). В этом случае просто получаете беззнаковое значение, и приписываете знак, определяемый битом знака.

Если это дополнение до 2 - то запоминаем знаковый бит, инвертируем все разряды, прибавляем 1 и получаем значение по модулю, после чего дописываем минус, если нужно.

У вас: 10110001 - 01001110 - 01001111, что равно 64+8+4+2+1=79, ну и знак минус...